# Python 3.5 cannot import a module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have read a ton of stackoverflow answers and a bunch of tutorials. In addition, I tried to read the Python documentation, but I cannot make this `import` work.

This is how the directory looks like:

```
myDirectory
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── LICENSE
    ├── project.py
    ├── README.md
    ├── stageManager.py
    └── tests
        ├── __init__.py
        └── test_project.py
```

There is a class in `project.py` called `Project`, and I want to import it in a file under `tests` directory. I have tried the following:

**Relative import**:

```
from ..project import Project

def print_sth():
    print("something")
```

This gives me the following error: (running from the `tests` directory as `python test_project.py` and from `myDirectory` as `python tests/test_project.py`)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "test_project.py", line 1, in <module>
       from ..project import Project
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

**Absolute import with package name**:

If I have something like the following, I get ImportError (with the same run command as above).

```
from project import Project

def print_sth():
    print("something")

------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "test_project.py", line 1, in <module>
        from project import Project
ImportError: No module named 'project'
```

and this too:

```
from myDirectory.project import Project

def print_sth():
    print("something")

------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "test_project.py", line 1, in <module>
       from myDirectory.project import Project 
ImportError: No module named 'myDirectory'
```

Finally, I tried adding the `if __name__ == '__main__'` statement within the `test_project.py` file, but it still failed.  I would really appreciate if anyone could help. If there is a solution where I do not have to write a verbose command, I would prefer that.

Comment: Have you tried simply `from project import Project` without the leading `..`?  Python imports are related to folder structure, but they are _not_ the folder structure and having the leading dots makes it skip the next module up, which is the one you want.

Comment: I tried that too, did not work. (I added the code and error up there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run a Python script by filename, the Python interpreter assumes that it is a top-level module (and it adds the directory the script is in to the module search path). If the script is in a package, that's not correct. Instead, you should run the module using the `-m` flag, which takes a module name in the same format as an import statement (dotted separators) and puts the current directory in the module search path.

So, you could run the test from `myDirectory` with: `python -m tests.test_project`. When you run the script this way, either of the kinds of imports you tried will work.

But if `myDirectory` is supposed to be a top-level package itself (as the `__init__.py` file suggests), you should probably go up one level further up, to `myDirectory`'s parent, and run the script with two levels of package names: `python -m myDirectory.tests.test_project`. If you do this and want the test to use an absolute import you'd need to name the top level package that the `project` module is in: `from myDirectory.project import Project`.

Comment: Thanks so much. I was able to run this from the `test_project` from `myDirectory` with the `-m` flag. However, it sort of restricts the usability of the module. Additionally, I would be dealing with a lot of `cd` and `mkdir` commands in this project. Is it possible to run `test_project.py` while in the `tests` directory?

Comment: You can add `myDirectory` (or it's parent) to the global module search path using environment variables (`PYTHONPATH`), and then do an absolute import from a script running anywhere. You could also then enable relative imports by setting the `__package__` variable in the script (see [PEP 366](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/) for details). But in general, running scripts from packages is not an encouraged idiom. You may want to have a top level entry point for scripts you're running frequently (it can just import and run some code from inside the package).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It appears that I need to look into the style guides more, and since a large part of my project is dependent on creating/modifying files/directories in different locations, I need to review some design principles and practices. Thanks for your effort!